# Variable Is Printing Out as String

Tags: python, json, string, variables, format

If I run `print(CURRENT_JSON)` then it prints out `ChunkName`, `ChunkId`, `m` and `LINE` as string, rather than printing out their values. How to fix it?

```
CURRENT_JSON = '{"ChunkName": "{ChunkName}", "ChunkData": {"ChunkId": "{ChunkId}", "MasterData": [{"Line": "{m}", "LData": "{LINE}"}]} }'
```

Comment: Prefix the string with `f` to make it a formatted string. So that would be `f"label: {value}"`.

Comment: Please post a working script. What are `ChunkName` and etc? Are they variables? Wouldn't it be more natural to have a python dict that you then serialize to json?

Comment: But it then shows another error "SyntaxError: f-string: expressions nested too deeply"

Comment: @Locke - mostly, but that doesn't account for json format characters in `value` that would break parsing.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, ChunkName, ChunkId, m and LINE are variables (string). Please tell me how can I fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't build JSON manually without considering escaping embedded control characters. For instance, what if one of these fields has a `"` character? Better to build a python dictionary and then serialize it.

```
import json

CURRENT_JSON = json.dumps({"ChunkName": ChunkName, 
    "ChunkData": {"ChunkId": ChunkId, 
    "MasterData": [{"Line": m, "LData": Line}]} })
```